# Angular - string with string value being passed as "[object object]"

Tags: angular, typescript

TLDR:
In my angular program I am passing a string as a parameter from the template. even though it has the correct value in the debugger, it is feeding through the functions (and ultimately back to the server) as "[object object]". I have tried JSON.stringify, and toString() but even after that, although they print correctly to console, they still pass through functions as "[object object]", and not as strings.

my code:

the object:

```
export interface Image {
    id: string;
    photoUrl: string;
    description: string;
}
```

relevant part of the component template:

```
<div class="col mb-5" *ngFor="let pho of currentAnimal.images">
...
 <a class="btn btn-outline-dark mt-auto" (click)="DeleteImage(pho.id)" >Remove Image</a>
```

the function in the component class:

```
 DeleteImage(photoId:string){
    
    //not sure why this is passing as an object:
    this.photoService.DeletePhoto(photoId).subscribe({

      error:(err)=>{console.log(err)},
      complete:()=>{
        let index = this.currentAnimal.images.findIndex(x=>x.id == photoId)
        this.currentAnimal.images.splice(index,1);
        this.toastr.success("Image has been deleted.");
      }
    })}
```

the function in my service passing it to the backend:

```
  DeletePhoto(PhotoId:string)
  {
   console.log("fired with: "+{PhotoId}) 
   return this.http.delete(this.baseUrl+'deletePhoto/'+{PhotoId});
  }
```

the above console.log consistently prints "[object object]", and that is also what is being passed to the backend. it didn't make any difference when I used JSON.stringify or toString() in the component function. in the debugger the string is just a string with it's correct value until passed to the backend.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks!

Comment: try this `console.log("photo", PhotoId)`

Comment: you're wrapping PhotoID with `{ }`, so naturally it becomes an Object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `{PhotoId}` You are creating an object with the `PhotoId` shorthand field, which is the same like `{ PhotoId: PhotoId }`. Simply remove the curly brackets.